# Moving dialog boxes shrinks window

Tags: 17.10, window, dialog

I've noticed in Ubuntu 17.10 that moving dialog boxes from some (any?) applications (such as "save as" or "open") also shrinks the window from the main application.

This is a bit annoying especially when saving a file and you just want to move the dialog box to see the title of the PDF file for example.

Any ideas as to how to correct this behavior?

Comment: Oops, yes indeed, it seems like a duplicate. Didn't look for the keyword "child window"...

Comment: I followed your instructions on the other thread. The "Tweaks" solution did the trick. But the other option "gsetting [...] false" doesn't work. There is a feature in Inkscape to "Live preview" the changes you want to make. And when checked, the window comes back to being attached.